# What is the default retention and archiving mechanism for Windows 2012 Event Logs?

Tags: windows-server-2012, logging, windows-event-log

- How does Windows 2012 manage event logs retention? Does it 'rotate' logs like *NIX systems?
- Does it automatically delete old logs when disk is full.
- Any way to define log retention period? (e.g. delete logs older than six months)

Comment: Have you looked at the properties for any of the logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Windows rotates it, and yes, there is a way to configure the retention policy.
And here is a pretty good article on Managing of event logs:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766178.aspx

Hope that gonna help

Comment: What do you mean by "rotates"?

Comment: I mean that it removes the old ones